# Get class from child and attr to closet parent

Tags: jquery

How can i get the class name of each div and attr it to the parent div.

I will be later removing the child class and unwraping it , so i need to keep the class intact but moved up to the parent element

HTML

```
<div>
 <div>
  <div class="hello"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Use jQuery to make parent of "child" class have same class

```
<div>
 <div class="hello">
  <div class="hello"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.hello').parent().addClass('hello');
```

This would make *any* parent element have the same class "hello". Although I cannot believe that it would make much sense.

For the more general case - see comments below - the following might help:

```
$('*').each(function(){
  var cls=this.className;
  $(this).removeClass(cls)
   .parent().addClass(cls);
})
```

Comment: class names are added dynamically , so i can not simply call out a class and add to parent , i have to find class of child and attr whatever that class name is to the parent

Comment: i will be removing child class , after attr same class to the parent

Comment: So, you want to "move" the class "one level up"? That would be quite a "sweeping statement" ...